# Pandas : How to get the postition (number of row) of a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my pandas dataframe and i need to find the index of a certain value.
But the thing is, this df does from an other one where i had to cut some part using the df.loc, so it ends up like :

```
index value
1448  31776
1449  32088
1450  32400
1451  32712
1452  33024
```

Let's say i need to find the index of the value '32400', with the function df.index[df.value == 32400] i get 1450, but what I want is 2.

Would you know how i could get this value?

Comment: you can use '''df.reset_index()'''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea is create default index starting by `0` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
idx = df.index[df.value == 32400]
print (idx)
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

Or use numpy - e.g. by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition for positions of match:

```
idx = np.where(df.value == 32400)[0]
print (idx)
[2]
```

Or use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) - it working well if match at least one value:

```
idx = np.argmax(df.value == 32400)
print (idx)
2

idx = np.argmax(df.value == 10)
print (idx)
0
```